# Alexnet poor Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently doing some machine learning for 10 leaf classes using Lenet and Alexnet architecture. Lenet gives 100% accuracy and about 90% predict accuracy, but Alexnet somehow only gives < 10% accuracy. Both architectures use the same epoch (50), datatrain (160 images), datavalidation (40 images), and batch_size(10). Why does this happen? Does this happen only in Alexnet because images count (200) are not enough for the amount of layers Alexnet has?

Dataset directory is:

```
dataset
├── class0
│   ├── image1
│   ├── ....
│   └── image20
│
├── ....
│   ├── image1
│   ├── ....
│   └── image20
│
└── class9
    ├── image1
    ├── ....
    └── image20
```

This is my Lenet model

```
#Instantiate an empty model
model = Sequential()

#Layer 1
#Conv Layer 1
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 6, 
                 kernel_size = 5, 
                 strides = 1, 
                 activation = 'relu', 
                 input_shape = (32,32,3)))

#Pooling layer 1
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))

#Layer 2
#Conv Layer 2
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, 
                 kernel_size = 5,
                 strides = 1,
                 activation = 'relu',
                 input_shape = (14,14,6)))
#Pooling Layer 2
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))
#Flatten
model.add(Flatten())

#Layer 3
#Fully connected layer 1
model.add(Dense(units = 120, activation = 'relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.4))

#Layer 4
#Fully connected layer 2
model.add(Dense(units = 84, activation = 'relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.4))

#Layer 5
#Output Layer
model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax'))
```

And this is my alexnet model

```
#Instantiate an empty model
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96,
          input_shape=(227,227,3),
          kernel_size=(11,11),
          strides=(4,4)))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(9216, input_shape=(227*227*3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss ='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer ='adam', metrics =['accuracy'])
```

I'm confused because the models are the only line codes that are changed.
This is Lenet accuracy

```
[0.1625, 0.33125, 0.51875, 0.64375, 0.75625, 0.83125, 0.85625, 0.93125, 0.96875, 0.98125, 0.99375, 0.98125, 0.98125, 0.9875, 0.98125, 0.99375, 0.99375, 0.99375, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

And this is Alexnet accuracy

```
[0.10625, 0.0875, 0.1, 0.1125, 0.125, 0.075, 0.08125, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.1, 0.1125, 0.06875, 0.1125, 0.0875, 0.10625, 0.05625, 0.10625, 0.06875, 0.0875, 0.0625, 0.0875, 0.06875, 0.11875, 0.1, 0.1125, 0.06875, 0.075, 0.1125, 0.0875, 0.075, 0.11875, 0.1125, 0.075, 0.0625, 0.13125, 0.075, 0.06875, 0.1, 0.1, 0.09375, 0.10625, 0.13125, 0.09375, 0.09375, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.0875, 0.10625, 0.0875]
```

Any helpful answers are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: your model has too many parameters, even if the accuracy is good, it's gonna overfit badly.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi I'm using [this](https://engmrk.com/alexnet-implementation-using-keras/) and [this](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/convolutional-neural-networks/classic-networks-MmYe2) as sources of my model, and I don't think I have too many parameters? which parameters do you mean?

Comment: `model.add(Dense(9216, input_shape=(227*227*3,)))` <- it's not in AlexNet.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi oh you are right. But I changed it to model.add(Dense(4096)) and it makes no improvement.

Comment: add more details about the dataset, also add implemention of LeNet.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi I added the directory and lenet model

Comment: Why 2 of your models have such different input dimensions?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi I just need to test between 2 architectures, which one is the best. I already set the img_width, img_height = 227, 227 in alexnet and img_width, img_height = 32, 32 in lenet for image_generator. I mean, if alexnet isnt usable, I can use lenet instead. I just want to know why the accuracy difference is so high.